# Adding Webdriver.io to project to test Electron app fails with syntax error on `import('wdio-electron-service/main')`

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron, webdriver-io

I am following the steps listed in [the webdriver.io electron-boilerplate repository](https://github.com/webdriverio/electron-boilerplate) and the steps in [the webdriver.io Electron Service documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/wdio-electron-service/)  but in my main.ts file, when I add:

```
    const isTest = process.env.NODE_ENV === "test";
    if (isTest) {
        import('wdio-electron-service/main');
    }
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot find module 'wdio-electron-service/main' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

If I don't include the erroring line (`import('wdio-electron-service/main');`) then the sample tests cannot connect to my electron app but the app builds. If I include the erroring line then the app doesn't build with:

```
 error  in ./node_modules/electron/index.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Git\PZX-D\PZX-Dashboard\node_modules\electron'

 error  in ./node_modules/electron/index.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\Git\PZX-D\PZX-Dashboard\node_modules\electron'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

 error  in src/main.ts:30:12

TS2307: Cannot find module 'wdio-electron-service/main' or its corresponding type declarations.
    28 |   const isTest = process.env.NODE_ENV === "test";
    29 |   if (isTest) {
  > 30 |     import('wdio-electron-service/main');
       |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    31 |   }
    32 |
    33 |   // Try refreshing the last user token

 ERROR  Vue CLI build failed. Please resolve any issues with your build and try again.
```

Comment: The documentation tells you to import on the preload, not on main

Comment: the documentation says to do both in main and in preload